# Python Library Camelot not reading all tables in one page

Tags: python, pdf, python-camelot

I'm using Camelot Python Library to read all tables in a page of pdf document

I'm tring to read all tables at page 10 in this [pdf](https://www.aci.it/fileadmin/documenti/studi_e_ricerche/auto-trend/2022/Auto-trend0122.pdf)

I tried to debug plotting the page and I noticed something if I change the flavor:

This is with flavor [lattice](https://postimg.cc/4mPq41fk)

This is with flavor [stream](https://postimg.cc/Mvqg8L8m)

The problem is if I use lattice flavor it will not read properly the tables
an example [here](https://postimg.cc/Mfb4Q71B)

If I use flavor='stream', It will read data properly but just of one table:
The [output](https://postimg.cc/JtbSvLSh) is somenthing like this.

I tried to use table_area/table_regions for detect the two tables with flavor='stream', but it didn't work.
I paste the code down here.

Code with lattice:

```
import camelot

file = "2022/Auto-trend0122.pdf" 
tables = camelot.read_pdf(file,pages='10',flavor='lattice',edge_tool=1500) 
print("Total tables extracted:", tables.n) 
print(tables[0].df) camelot.plot(tables[0],filename="try_plot.png", kind='contour') 
print(tables[1].df)
```

Code with stream, without table_area/table_regions:

```
import camelot

file = "2022/Auto-trend0122.pdf"
tables = camelot.read_pdf(file,pages='10',flavor='stream', edge_tool=1500)
print("Total tables extracted:", tables.n)
print(tables[0].df)
camelot.plot(tables[0],filename="try_plot.png", kind='contour')
```

Code with stream, with table_area:

```
import camelot

file = "2022/Auto-trend0122.pdf"
tables = camelot.read_pdf(file,pages='10',flavor='stream',edge_tool=1500,table_area=['10,450,550,50','10,750,550,450'])
print("Total tables extracted:", tables.n)
print(tables[0].df)
camelot.plot(tables[0],filename="try_plot.png", kind='contour')
```

Code with stream, with table_regions:

```
import camelot

file = "2022/Auto-trend0122.pdf"
tables = camelot.read_pdf(file,pages='10',flavor='stream',edge_tool=1500,table_regions=['10,450,550,50','10,750,550,450'])
print("Total tables extracted:", tables.n)
print(tables[0].df)
camelot.plot(tables[0],filename="try_plot.png", kind='contour')
```

The output for table_*regions/table*_area/without is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using table_area instead of the correct parameter `table_areas` (read the [docs](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced.html#specify-table-areas)).

The following command works perfectly:

`tables = camelot.read_pdf(file,pages='10', flavor='stream', edge_tool=1500, table_areas=['10,450,550,50','10,750,550,450'])`

**Difference between table_areas and table_regions**

`table_areas` should be used when you know the exact position of the table. Conversely, `table_regions` makes the detection engine look for tables only in those generic page regions.